# Did the Kali Linux Persistence just destroy my new usb drive?

Tags: kali-linux, usb-storage

Sometimes life just doesn't want you to go into a certain direction. Today I decided to get into Kali Linux, so I actually went to the tech-store to buy a 32GB Intenso USB 3.1 flash drive. Since I wanted some persistence on it, I followed the standard documentation to install it and later used Mini Tool Partition Manager to use the remaining space as my persistence storage in ext4, seemingly the standard way of doing this. After I booted up my Kali installation, I used `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. The latter took quite some time, and showed me that some archives were missing I think, I can't fully remember.

So after it was finished I tried to install a package using `sudo`, but got an error which stated the the user 'kali' couldn't be found or something and the issue would be reported(?). I figured that a restart could maybe fix my problem, but when I shut down the machine the screen showed many error messages with timestamps infront of them rapidly.

Long story short, my brand new flashdrive doesn't get recognised by either the boot-menu, windows explorer, nor commands like `lsblk` or `lsusb` on a completely different computer.

How can I find out if the flashdrive is actually broken beyond fixing?

This is my `dmesg` output after I insert the flash-drive:

```
[   32.160515] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   32.314576] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=3267, bcdDevice= 1.00
[   32.314583] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   32.314588] usb 1-2: Product: SM3269AB MEMORY BAR 
[   32.314592] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Silicon Motion,Inc. 
[   32.316779] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   32.317432] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[   33.345945] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SMI      USB MEMORY BAR   1000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[   33.346892] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[   33.347561] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Comment: Kali doesn't flash the firmware or do anything else strange to the drive, so if it's dead it's because the drive was defective or low quality. Do you get any messages about the USB in dmesg when you plug it in or pull it out?

Comment: This is not an information security question, so it will likely be closed or moved elsewhere. Also, since additional back and forth may be needed to troubleshoot, you may be better off posting on a forum since Q&A isn't ideal. That said, is there any output in `dmesg` when you plug it in?

Comment: Is that the whole USB related `dmesg` after you insert the drive? Usually that's followed by a couple more lines. Could you recheck please?

Answer (score 0):

It takes a bit of puzzling to understand what happened.

The message that you got from `sudo` is probably `

> Username is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported

When written in full like this, it should be clear what the problem is: the user kali is not in the sudoers-file and in therefore not allowed to sudo. This will be reported to the sysadmin of the system (which is you), so don't worry about that.

When `apt-get` shows that archives are missing, run `apt-get update –fix-missing` or something like that, and repeat the cycle `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade`. `apt-get` should leave your system in a consistent state, but I generally like to fix the errors before rebooting.

The fact that WIndows explorer does not recognise the drive is a Windows problem. Windows is not very good in recognizing non-Windows file systems.

You say that `lsusb` does not see the drive; however, your output from `dmesg` suggests that the drive is recognized. That is inconsistent and would require a bit of additional examination. Also, the output from `dmesg` is (to me) strange.

```
sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
```

And specially, the `sg1`. This is normally `sdx`, with x a letter. You should then be able to find that device under `/dev`. So, on your system, is there a `/dev/sg1`? And if so, what does it say when you `fdisk -l /dev/sg1`? (take the `sg1` from the dmesg output; the actual name might be different next time)

With fdisk, you get the partition table on the flash-drive. If you want to start from the beginning, you can just re-initialize the drive.

Answer (score -1):

There are many fake flash drives around (even store-bought ones).
I would test the USB drive to see if it really is a 32GB drive - Google for 'Fake Flash test' to test the drive. Just because it says 32GB under Linux\Windows doesn't mean that it is!

Comment: The drive currently isn't detected, as described by OP.